# Number of cut sets and the length of the shortest path?

Tags: graph-theory

If s and t are two nodes in a graph.
How to prove that the maximum number of edge-disjoint cut sets which divide s and t equals the length of the shortest path from s to t?

Comment: What have you done to get started?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

First show that the size of any collection of edge-disjoint cut-sets cannot exceed the length of the shortest path.

Comment: Yes! I've known how to prove it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this paper might be of use:

http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/page/jise/2001/200103_02.pdf

Comment: Thank you all the same. But there is no proof in this paper. It has only mentioned this conclusion.